# Steam cannot be installed Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: steam

No matter what I do, I am impossible to install Steam on a clean, fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2.

There are unmet dependencies that are impossible to fix. How come Steam does not release a version/installer that just works on Ubuntu? I thought they were very pro-Linux.

I tried downloading the missing dependencies manually and install them, but even that fails, probably because each package has its own (other) dependencies, which have their own dependencies etc etc.

```
 sudo apt install ./* && sudo apt --fix-broken install ./*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1 : Breaks: libgl1:i386 (!= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.3.1-1 is installed
 libgl1:i386 : Breaks: libgl1 (!= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) but 20.0.4-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.100) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libllvm9:i386 (>= 1:9~svn298832-1~) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libsensors5:i386 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.2.131.2) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libzstd1:i386 (>= 1.3.2) but it is not installed
                        Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not installed
                        Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 is installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not installed
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) but 20.0.4-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 is installed
 libglvnd0 : Breaks: libglvnd0:i386 (!= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.3.1-1 is installed
 libglvnd0:i386 : Breaks: libglvnd0 (!= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
 libglx0 : Breaks: libglx0:i386 (!= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1.3.1-1 is installed
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not installed
                Breaks: libglx0 (!= 1.3.1-1) but 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even if I go down that rabbithole, I keep seeing the same error, new dependencies popping up:

```
asterix@Idefix:~/Downloads/Steam$ sudo apt install wget gdebi-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version (1.20.3-1ubuntu1).
wget set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
asterix@Idefix:~/Downloads/Steam$ sudo apt -f install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
asterix@Idefix:~/Downloads/Steam$ sudo apt -f install libgl1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
asterix@Idefix:~/Downloads/Steam$ sudo apt -f install libglvnd0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgles2 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.8+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
asterix@Idefix:~/Downloads/Steam$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386=20.0.4-2ubuntu1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It seems completely impossible to get Steam to run on the latest (not that new actually) version of Ubuntu (while 20.10 is out already).

Is this solvable or is Steam no longer supporting Ubuntu?

Comment: it maybe your configuration because i can install steam on any xubuntu 20.04 machine from the software/repo i have in my home and i havent got to install any dependencies or whatever.

Comment: What do version do you get when you `dpkg -l | grep libgl1`?  Also what is the contents of the files in /etc/apt/sources.list and  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* This version naming difference 1.3.1-1 vs 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 makes it look like there is something in your sources that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Experiencing a very similar issue with my Ubuntu. Did you find any way to resolve your problem @zilexa?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install aptitude`, `sudo aptitude install steam`. **Note:** you don't have to actually confirm the installation, as it can apply some aggressive conflict resolution. Just show us the output.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem: `dist-upgrade` removed my Steam and I couldn't install it back.
I couldn't roll back the updated packages, because the previous versions were no longer in the repo (?!).

Turns out I had `libllvm11 11.0.1` installed, which conflicts with `libllvm11:i386 11.0.0` needed by Steam.

They only conflict because the version is different, so I downgraded `libllvm11` to `11.0.0` (and Clang, and all related packages).

Here's what exactly I did:

- First: `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` Make sure this didn't fix the problem.
- Install Aptitude, since it seems to have smarter conflict resolution. `sudo apt install aptitude`
- Start the Steam installation using Aptitude, **but don't confirm the installation**. You just want to see the output. `sudo aptitude install -s steam` (`-s` means doing a dry run without actually installing).

  For me, Aptitude proposed a very aggressive conflict resolution plan which I didn't like, which removed some packages.

  But it also explained what was wrong. It said:

  ```
  libllvm11 : Breaks: libllvm11:i386 (!= 1:11.0.1~++20201218093155+43ff75f2c3fe-1~exp1~20201218203809.158) but have installed 1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1
  libllvm11:i386 : Breaks: libllvm11 (!= 1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1) but installing 1:11.0.1~++20201218093155+43ff75f2c3fe-1~exp1~20201218203809.158
  ```

  <sup>(translated to English manually, actual output might be slightly different)</sup>

  Basically, it says that it needs to install `libllvm11:i386`, which conflicts with the installed `libllvm11`. But it only conflicts because they have different versions; you can have both installed at the same time if the version is the same. But the version of `libllvm11:i386` available in the repos is older than the version of `libllvm11` that I had installed.
- The solution is to downgrade `libllvm11` to the suggested version: `sudo apt install libllvm11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1`.

  This uninstalled my Clang 11 and related tools, because they wanted the latest LLVM version. Probably they won't be uninstalled if you downgrade them at the same time, but for me it was easier to reinstall them later.
- Now you should be able to install Steam: `sudo aptitude install steam`.

  Before confirming the installation, make sure it no longer wants to remove any packages.
- Now you might want to get your Clang 11 back. I attempted:

  ```
  sudo apt install \
      clang-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clangd-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clang-tools-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clang-tidy-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      lld-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1
  ```

  Note the version matching the manually installed version of `libllvm11`.

  Note that we're using `apt` this time, since in this case it gives better error messages.

  I got following:

  ```
  clang-11 : Depends on: libclang-cpp11 but it won't be installed
             Depends on: libclang-common-11-dev (= 1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1) but it won't be installed
             Depends on: libclang1-11 (= 1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1) but 1:11.0.1~++20201218093155+43ff75f2c3fe-1~exp1~20201218203809.158 must be installed
             Recommends: llvm-11-dev but it won't be installed
             Recommends: libomp-11-dev but it won't be installed
  clang-tidy-11 : Depends on: libclang-cpp11 but it won't be installed
                  Depends on: libclang-common-11-dev but it won't be installed
  clang-tools-11 : Depends on: libclang-cpp11 but it won't be installed
  clangd-11 : Depends on: libclang-cpp11 but it won't be installed
              Depends on: libclang-common-11-dev (= 1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1) but it won't be installed
  ```

  <sup>(translated to English manually, actual output might be slightly different)</sup>

  We add all of those packages to the command, with the same `=<version>` suffix, then we repeat the same thing (around 3 times) until we arrive at following:

  ```
  sudo apt install \
      clang-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clangd-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clang-tools-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      clang-tidy-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      lld-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      libclang-cpp11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      libclang-common-11-dev=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      libclang1-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      llvm-11-dev=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      libomp-11-dev=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      libomp5-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      llvm-11=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      llvm-11-tools=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1 \
      llvm-11-runtime=1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1
  ```

  Which actually works and installs Clang.
- Then we mark all of those dependencies as "automatically installed", so that they won't linger around when you no longer need them.

  (I'm not sure if this step does anything useful, but it doesn't hurt.)

  We do it for all packages in the command above (except the first 5, which we actually need), plus `libllvm11`.

  ```
  sudo apt-mark auto \
      libllvm11 \
      libclang-cpp11 \
      libclang-common-11-dev \
      libclang1-11 \
      llvm-11-dev \
      libomp-11-dev \
      libclang-cpp11 \
      libclang-common-11-dev \
      libclang-cpp11 \
      libclang-cpp11 \
      libclang-common-11-dev \
      libomp5-11 \
      llvm-11 \
      llvm-11-tools \
      llvm-11-runtime
  ```
- Finally, `sudo apt ugprade`, `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: Sadly, steam ist not available for ubuntu 20.04 anymore.
You would need to update to impish (21.10).
Is there a way to do this with the downloadable deb package?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using:

```
~$ sudo apt install aptitude
~$ sudo aptitude install steam
```

During install, I said no to the first question:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libudev1:i386 [Not Installed]                      
2)     steam:i386 [Not Installed]                         

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
3)     steam-devices recommends steam                     

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

I said yes to the next question:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:                            
1)     libudev1 [245.4-4ubuntu3.4 (now) -> 245.4-4ubuntu3 (focal)]
2)     udev [245.4-4ubuntu3.4 (now) -> 245.4-4ubuntu3 (focal)]    

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

I finally started steam which launched at first the steam updater:

```
~$ steam
```